# Upload to SSH in XMODEM manner?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, upload

I know I can use scp command and copy any file whenever I can come with ssh client.

But let see in more detail. Suppose I have ALREADY logged in with ssh client. This means that I have ALREADY entered server name, and user's name and password. Also suppose I made some `cd`s. This means I have ALREADY entered destination directory.

I don't want to enter this data AGAIN. I just see no any reason to do any work twice.

Now I want to UPLOAD some file into THAT place, where I am already am.

Is it possible to do that?

In the times of telephone modems, there were several protocols, allowing server to initiate file upload by client. If I entered some command, my terminal client was opening file select dialog and I was able to select file to upload.

Decades passed. Is this possible now in 21 century?

Comment: I think so. My terminal emulator (Konsole) has an option `ZModem Upload` in the menu. Of course, you would have to have the correct software on the server side, which is unlikely these days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this method is *easier* than just using scp, and I'm going to make many assumtions about what ssh client you're using and what OS your source and destination machines have. I just hope this is helpful.

If you have already logged in to the machine, and want to transfer one file without having to log in again, you can open a tunnel like this:

- In the command line, type ~C, you will enter ssh's command console:

`ssh>`

- Type -L 4444:localhost:4444 to forward port 4444 on your local machine to port 4444 on the remote machine

`ssh> -L 4444:localhost:4444
Forwarding port.`

- When you see your prompt on your remote machine again, enter:

`nc -l 4444 > my_file.txt`

This will listen on port 4444 and send the output to my_file.txt

- Now, on your local machine, you do:

`nc localhost 4444 < my_file.txt`

And that will send my_file.txt over the ssh forwarded tunnel to the remote machine, and netcat (nc command) will pipe it to the file in the remote machine. If you want to transfer an entire directory, use `tar` and redirect to standard input and from standard output. (`man tar` is your friend).

Comment: I find I have to specify the listen port with -p or it is ignored.  And it doesn't auto-terminate for files that don't include an EOF.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like SecureCRT (Windows) or iTerm2 (Mac), you can use Zmodem to transfer files back and forth without using scp/nc/etc. I use this to quickly move files back and forth without having to open a second session. The Unix server will need to have the lrzsz package installed -- some distros have this installed by default, some don't.

If you're using SecureCRT, you can just run "sz filename.txt" and the transfer will start automatically; running "rz" will pop up a file selection box. If you're on iTerm2, you have to do a little bit of configuration to make it work, starting with installing the lrzsz package (via Homebrew or another package manager), and then configure iTerm2 to listen for the Zmodem character sequence. That's described here: https://github.com/aurora/iterm2-zmodem